# MATLAB, GUIDE, viewing the slice number on a dicom stack

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want to view the number of the slice that I'm examining via a simple previous/next slice GUI. I store number of the slice that I'm viewing on `handles.index` and I'm able to update it via the previous, next pushbuttons.

I wrote the following on the edit text callback function:

```
function edit2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.output=hObject
set (edit2.handles,'Tag', handles.index); %also tried with the 'String' property and failed
```

The Property is not updating when the code is running. It remains as 'Edit Text', what's wrong here?

[Full Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gidpsqt36rqph9/PREVIOUS_NEXT_GUI.m), [Dicom file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/91eha9wlkg5cdwa/TumorSimOutput2_T1.dcm)

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I made the update on the pushbutton callbacks, and it works fine :)

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.output = hObject;
handles.index = handles.index+1;
Cek (hObject, eventdata, handles);
imshow(handles.image_data(:,:,handles.index),'DisplayRange',[]); 
set (handles.edit2,'String', handles.index);
```